# Javascript or JQuery: Deactivate a radiobutton

Tags: jquery, radio-button

http://jsfiddle.net/tearex/jFS2x/4/

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"  >
    <input name="btn1" id="a1" type="radio"  />
    <label for="a1">1 populate USA</label>

    <input name="btn1" id="a2" type="radio" />
    <label for="a2" class="bigga">2 populate Germany</label>

    <select data-role="slider" id="how" >
        <option value="naturally" accesskey=""    >naturally</option>
        <option value="forcibly"  > forcibly</option>
    </select>           
</fieldset>
```

How to make the deactivated button gray off instantly?

I tried this:

```
document.getElementById("a1").disabled = true;
$("[id='how']").slider("disable")
```

but unlike the slider, the button does not become gray until I click the  other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jFS2x/5/)

You're disabling it alright but jquery mobile CSS is not showing it. The radio button is actually wrapped in a div with class `ui-radio` & to visually see that it's disabled a new class needs to be added `ui-disabled`.

```
$('#a1').prop('disabled',true);
$('#a1').parent('.ui-radio').addClass('ui-disabled');
```

Note: Please don't mix javascript & jquery(ofcourse for a few exceptions.) You shouldn't be writing `document.getElementById("a1").disabled = true;` where you could've written `$('#a1').prop('disabled',true);`

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$("#a1").checkboxradio('disable');
```

instead of manually disabling the input.

Also see http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/radiobuttons/methods.html